# Libgdx Directional Collision Detection for Pacman Clone

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm using Libgdx to make a Pacman clone and I am having an issue with collision.

I I'm bringing in square objects made in the tile editor to determine where the walls are. Here is my map code that handles that.

```
public void getMapColliders()
{
    MapObjects collisionObjects = new MapObjects();
    collisionObjects = map.getLayers().get("Level Boundries").getObjects();
    int tileWidth = 16; // whatever your tile width is
    int tileHeight = 16; // whatever your tile height is

    for (int i = 0; i < collisionObjects.getCount(); i++)
    {
        RectangleMapObject obj = (RectangleMapObject) collisionObjects.get(i);
        Rectangle rect = obj.getRectangle();

        collisionRects.add(new Rectangle((int)rect.x+2,(int) rect.y+16, rect.width , rect.height));

    }
}
```

I then have a rectangle around my Pacman sprite to act as a collision box and using the overlap function to detect collision. Initially I had it save the last position of Pacman before moving forward and if it detected a collision it reset the position. This didn't work and I got stuck in the walls, instead I ended up just reversing the movement the same amount it moved forward and that worked, but because how perfectly aligned the sprite and map are it would always put Pacman in a position where he couldn't go down because he is slightly off to one side or the other. Here is the code for that:

```
package Components;

import Math.Point2D;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller
{

    /* Variable to store amount entitie position should increase */
    private Input input;
    private String keyPressed;
    private String lastKeyPressed;
    private boolean isMoving;
    private double speed;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> mapCollisionBoxes;
    private Collider pCol;
    private boolean rBlocked;
    private boolean lBlocked;
    private boolean uBlocked;
    private boolean dBlocked;
    private Point2D prevPos;

    //private Point2D movementP;
    public Controller(ArrayList<Rectangle> collisions, Collider pCol)
    {
        input = new Input();
        keyPressed = "N";
        lastKeyPressed = "N";
        isMoving = false;
        speed = 40.0;
        mapCollisionBoxes = collisions;
        this.pCol = pCol;
        prevPos = new Point2D();

    }

    /**
     * Check if a movement input is pressed and move accordingly
     *
     * @param curPos Player's current position
     * @param t Delta time
     */
    public void move(Point2D curPos, int t)
    {
        System.out.println("rBlocked: " + rBlocked);
        System.out.println("lBlocked: " + lBlocked);
        System.out.println("uBlocked: " + uBlocked);
        System.out.println("dBlocked: " + dBlocked);
        keyPressed = input.checkKeys();
        switch (keyPressed)
        {
            case "RIGHT":
                lastKeyPressed = "R";
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                lastKeyPressed = "L";
                break;
            case "UP":
                lastKeyPressed = "U";
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                lastKeyPressed = "D";
                break;
            case "NONE":
                break;
        }

        switch (lastKeyPressed)
        {
            case "R":
                if (!rBlocked)
                {
                    if (checkForCollision())
                    {
                        curPos.setX(curPos.getX() - speed * t / 1000);
                        rBlocked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curPos.setX(curPos.getX() + speed * t / 1000);
                        lBlocked = false;
                        dBlocked = false;
                        uBlocked = false;
                    }
                }

                break;

            case "L":
                if (!lBlocked)
                {
                    prevPos = curPos;
                    if (checkForCollision())
                    {
                        curPos.setX(Math.round(curPos.getX() + speed * t / 1000));
                        lBlocked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curPos.setX(curPos.getX() - speed * t / 1000);
                        rBlocked = false;
                        uBlocked = false;
                        dBlocked = false;

                    }
                }
                break;

            case "U":
                if (!uBlocked)
                {
                    if (checkForCollision())
                    {
                        curPos.setY(curPos.getY() - speed * t / 1000);
                        uBlocked = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curPos.setY(curPos.getY() + speed * t / 1000);
                        dBlocked = false;
                        lBlocked = false;
                        rBlocked = false;

                    }
                }
                break;

            case "D":
                if (!dBlocked)
                {
                    if (checkForCollision())
                    {
                        curPos.setY(Math.round(curPos.getY() + speed * t / 1000));
                        dBlocked = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curPos.setY(curPos.getY() - speed * t / 1000);
                        uBlocked = false;
                        lBlocked = false;
                        rBlocked = false;

                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public String lastKeyPressed()
    {
        return lastKeyPressed;
    }

    private boolean checkForCollision()
    {
        boolean collided = false;
        for (Rectangle rect : mapCollisionBoxes)
        {
            if (pCol.hBox.overlaps(rect))
            {
                collided = true;
            }
        }
        return collided;
    }

}
```

This is all on top of the fact that I have to use booleans to check which direction he was going when he collided otherwise he would never move again after hitting something because collision isn't directional. This creates and old glitch I had in another game where if I'm stopped on the left side and hit right then left again quickly I will pass through the wall slightly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.